# How do I read the List<object> that I have made from a csv file

Tags: c#

I was tasked to make a Trivia Game with two parts. Part A I was allowed to use 3 Lists<> for my Questions, Answers, and Points. Part A I am done with. Now I have to do Part B where I am supposed to only use 1 List<>. This is one of the Advanced assignments that we have in my class and most of them are stuff we haven't been taught so I have to use any resources I have.

I have this code from a different thread on how to read csv files into a List of objects:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Trivia> values = File.ReadAllLines("TriviaQuestions.csv").Select(v => Trivia.FromCsv(v)).ToList();    
    }
}

class Trivia
{
    string Questions;
    string Answers;
    int Points;

    public static Trivia FromCsv(string csvLine)
    {            
        string[] values = csvLine.Split(',');
        Trivia triviaGame = new Trivia();
        triviaGame.Questions = values[0];
        triviaGame.Answers = values[1];
        triviaGame.Points = int.Parse(values[2]);
        return triviaGame;         
    }
}
```

It reads it perfectly, but my question is where does it go? What line of code do I need in the main program in order to read the lines that I have split from the csv file. Essentially, where does it all go after I run the program so that I can read each questions one by one and have the user answer it which is the easy part. I can clarify further if the question doesn't make sense.

Comment: *where does it all go after I run the program* into memory ...

Comment: Sorry, couldn't articulate well enough what I meant. How to output the data after reading the CSV file is what I meant!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a lot of questions to this post, so I'll try to answer the easiest I can with references.

```
It reads it perfectly, but my question is where does it go?
```

You're reading the values into a `List` data structure. `Lists` are stored on the heap.
To understand more, take a look at:
https://jonskeet.uk/csharp/memory.html

```
What line of code do I need in the main program in order to read the lines that I have split from the csv file
```

What you need to do is first output the questions you've read into your `List`. Next, you'll want to receive the `Input` from the user, and store that (in another `List`) so that you can reference them later on (if you need to).

To output data to the user, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.writeline?view=netframework-4.8

To read data from the user, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.readline?view=netframework-4.8

After you are done understanding basic console reading and writing, you can do something like:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var questions = File.ReadAllLines("TriviaQuestions.csv").Select(v => Trivia.FromCsv(v)).ToList();    
    var answers = new List<string>();

    foreach (var question in questions)
    {
       Console.WriteLine(question.Questions);

        var answer = Console.ReadLine();
        answers.Add(answer);
    }


    Console.WriteLine("The user answers are...");
    foreach (var answer in answers)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(answer);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. It has helped quite a bit, being refreshed with the basic definitely help. Unfortunately, after testing out your recommendation, the only thing Console.Writeline(question) writes is the _Namespace_.trivia?

Comment: @Rhett oops, forgot to update based on the trivia object. hold tight

Comment: @Rhett it's kind of hard to determine if the Trivia class is correct because I don't know what the structure of the CSV is.. but see update

Comment: Oops, forgot to add that. CSV file is basically this `question,answers,points` @d.moncada

Comment: It works perfectly. Thanks so much. You see, I was aware of what I needed to do. I just couldn't for the life of me figure out how to read out the data to the user. This has been a good learning experience for me and I thank you very much for the help! @d.moncada

Comment: @Rhett no problem.. we all have those hiccups somethings. glad you figured it out!